# Unable to Upload certain Documents in salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, force.com-sites, site.com

[image]We have developed a site for our client to place order which will get created as Record in the Order Object.

The form will redirect them to next pages to fill all mandatory fields to place the order . Before the Preview page Or Submit page there will be page which will have option for the client to upload the Document.

The Issue is for two of our client in the Document upload page when they tried to upload a Document It throws a Common Authentication error which is Set in the

However the site is not set in such way for the guest User to login prior and then to place order. Anybody using the link can Place the order.

Secondly ,When we try to overcome this error, We found by changing the Document we were able to eliminate the Error. But we were unable to understand why we are unable to upload this Document.

When I edited one of the Document Header and there was another document inside a Document I removed it as well ,and then Tried It worked. For the Second Document it did not have header or Other Document attached in it,yet it throws this common error.

Since we cannot ask our client to re edit the Document. It is now we to find the reason why these Two documents are not uploading through the form.

Controller Class for the Online Order Form:

```
public without sharing class NewOrderController {

 public Attachment attachment {
    get {
        if (attachment == null)
            attachment = new Attachment();
        return attachment;
    }
    set;
}

public boolean isFileUploaded{get; set;}
public String uploadFileName{get; set;}      
public PageReference upload() {                      

    ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.INFO,'Attachment uploaded successfully'));
    return null;
}

public void uploadFile() {                                       
    attachment.IsPrivate = true;        
    uploadFileName = attachment.Name;
    isFileUploaded = true;                
}
//Attachment Part in the Class

  if(order.Type_Of_Order__c=='New Client or Web Time Branch'|| order.Type_Of_Order__c== 'Redeploy' || order.Type_Of_Order__c== 'Reactivation')
        {
            try{
                if(attachment!=null && attachment.Name!=null){   
                    attachment.IsPrivate = true;        
                    uploadFileName = attachment.Name;
                    isFileUploaded = true;
                    attachment.ParentId = orderList.get(0).Id;
                    insert attachment;
                    attachment =null;
                }
            }
            catch (DMLException e) {   
                attachment = new Attachment();
                System.debug('Attachment issue: ' + e.getMessage() + ' : ' + e.getLineNumber());                        
            }
        }
```

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

The above pic is the Default error that appears when we upload that particular Two Word Document. However this error message was not called anywhere in the class.[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[image]

Comment: Hi (username), welcome to SFSE! Please take the time to visit the [Help] and read [How do I ask a good question](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). If you could share details from the headers that's causing the issues, you're much more likely to get an answer you'll find helpful to you. Code from your form that's causing the error to be thrown might also prove helpful.

Comment: Hi I have updated my question with the information you asked.

Comment: @crmprogdev Nice boilerplate! Delicious copy-pasta.